# Different results with 2 Postgres instances

Tags: postgresql, heroku, go

I run a Postgres 9.2.2 server locally using the [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com) with `ssmode=disable`. All the tables are created like they should be and `SELECT` queries work as expected.

When I create a Postgres instance on [Heroku](https://postgres.heroku.com) (the server is 9.1.6 according to `psql`, `ssmode=require`), everything works fine, except that a query returns no results, where the local postgres instance does.

The specific query is

```sql
SELECT * FROM "captcha" WHERE "cid" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

and `cid`/`$1` is of type `character varying(20)`.

When connecting to the remote instance via `psql` and executing the query manually, the rows were returned as expected. I just don't understand what could possibly cause that different  behavior.

The primary suspect would be the driver that I use [bmizerany/pq](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq), but could there be other error sources for this behavior?

UPDATE:

I tried it with a plain query, same result: No rows in result set

```
SELECT * FROM "captcha" WHERE "cid" = 'JQRPm6qRpYukXCiPUpHZ' LIMIT 1
```

UPDATE 2:

It has something todo with the `bytea` field, the following snippet illustrates the problem when executing on those 2 PG versions https://gist.github.com/eaigner/5004468

Comment: Could you print the exact query that's being executed?

Comment: What do you mean by "the exact query"? I posted the prepared statement already.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but if you just execute `SELECT * FROM "captcha"` do you see the correct row in that result set?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct row when I do the query with `psql`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not familiar with pq/go, so I wasn't sure whether that was a prepared statement or client-side escaping. Anyway, I was intending: "the exact query that's being executed by your program"… But if it's prepared, a couple dumb sanity checks: are you sure the values in your program are correct? Are you connecting to the right database? Do any rows show up when you query from software? (as jcern suggests)?

Comment: 1) Yes, the values are correct because I log every executed SQL statement and it's parameters in development 2) Yes, the connection string is the right one, checked that already - also every other SQL commands works, so it can't be the connection

Comment: Dang. That's… Very weird. The only other thing I'd wonder: if you 'select * from "captcha"', does the row eventually get returned?

Comment: No, even if I select all rows no rows are returned.

Comment: Another stupid question, but just to double check: is `captcha` a normal table? Or is it a view?

Comment: It's definitely a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that Heroku uses a non-default `bytea_output`. So a workaround to deal with this was

```
SET bytea_output = 'hex';
```

before running the query

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE`. `pq` uses the 'extended' query protocol which uses bind rather than the 'simple' protocol that is just text, so that'll model the interaction better.

Please file a bug.

Comment: Oh, you're one of the maintainers! I already filed an [issue](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq/issues/80) for it.